# How do I pass component's ownProps to reduxForm?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

`this.props.data` is not defined

```
   initialValues: {
      data: this.props.data
    }
```

Here's more code below:

```
const mapState = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(ownProps.formData)
  return {
    data: ownProps.formData
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapState,
    null
  ),
  reduxForm({
    form: "info-form",
    initialValues: {
      data: this.props.data
    }
  })
)(InfoForm)
```

`ownProps.formData` is an array of objects. I can see it when I'm logging it in the console in `mapState`. If I create `const data=[{...},{...}]` outside of my form component and reference it like:

```
initialValues: {
  data: data
}
```

the form works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of using `initialValues`, one is to pass it as in the object passed to `reduxForm` HOC, the other way is while you import this component somewhere else in the project you can pass it as

```
<InfoForm initialValues={{ data }} />
```

Please refer this link here https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/initializefromstate/. It clearly states that

> Values provided to the initialValues prop or reduxForm() config parameter will be loaded into the form state and treated thereafter as "pristine"

Comment: Perfect. It works. `<InfoForm initialValues={{ data: formData }} />`